# Is the following a correct proof for the interval covering problem?

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

I have written the following greedy stays ahead proof for the problem of covering an interval with subintervals. Is it correct? I think it is, but this is my first time proving a greedy algorithm.

Suppose you have a set of $n$ subintervals $\{1, 2,...,n\}$, and each subinterval has a left and right end $(l_i, r_i)$. The goal is to find the minimal selection of intervals to completely cover an interval $(x_1, x_2)$. We build a solution left to right by repeatedly selecting the subinterval whose left end overlaps or coincides with the right end of our covered interval so far and extends the right end of the interval as much as possible. We wish to prove that this produces an optimal solution.

Let $A = \{i_1, i_2, i_3, ..., i_k\}$ be the subintervals selected by our greedy algorithm, in the order in which they were added. Let $O = \{j_1, j_2, j_3, ..., j_m\}$ be an optimal solution, ordered by the left end of the subintervals in ascending order. Let $f(S)$ be the right end of the portion of the interval covered by $S$. We wish to show that for all $r \leq k$, $f(i_1, ..., i_r) \geq f(j_1, ..., j_r)$.

We show this by induction. As the base case, take $r = 1$. The first subinterval selected by the greedy algorithm is the subinterval that extends as far as possible to the right, so certainly $f(i_1) \geq f(j_1)$.

For $t > 1$, we assume the statement is true for $t-1$ and prove it for $t$. Our induction hypothesis states that $f(i_1, ..., i_{t-1}) \geq f(j_1, ..., j_{t-1})$, so any subintervals available to the optimal solution for the next choice are certainly available to the greedy solution. Since the greedy solution chooses the subinterval that extends as far as possible to the right, greedy stays ahead of the optimal solution. In other words, $f(i_1, ..., i_t) \geq f(j_1, ..., j_t)$

So we have for all $r \leq k, f(i_1, ..., i_r) \geq f(j_1, ..., j_r)$. Consider $f(j_1, ..., j_m)$, the optimal solution. Since we proved that greedy stays ahead, we have $f(i_1, ..., i_m) \geq f(j_1, ..., j_m)$. In other words, our greedy solution extends at least as far as the optimal solution in $m$ subintervals. Since the greedy solution terminates once it completely covers the entire interval, $|A| = |O|$, so the greedy solution is optimal.